# When running crawl space conduit, must the conduit be run through the joist via drilled holes, or can they be attached underneath?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit, data-wiring

I'm wiring my home for 110V and cat6e(48-0V).  There is currently no wiring, just an air tight shell with interior studs exposed.  There is a crawl space where I would like to run all of the conduit for both my standard electrical power and ethernet POE cat6.  Is there any reason I need to drill holes in the floor joists and fish the conduit through those holes, or can I simply secure the conduit to bottom of the joists using brackets of some sort?

Comment: What type of conduit are you running here? The support requirements are different for rigid metal vs rigid nonmetallic vs flex...

Comment: It’s better to attach to joist rather than drill holes through the joists for conduit. You run the risk of over drilling a joist and weakening it...get some clips and screw the conduit to the joists.

Comment: Also is this crawlspace *insulated*/*encapsulated* or *vented*?